# InvokeAsync order

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have different scenario, than in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19315744/1997232), therefore another question.

Let's take following example:

```
void PerformanceCriticalMethod()
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Log.Add("1"));
    ... some job
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Log.Add("2"));
}
```

`Invoke` creates performance problems. In attempt to fix it I used `InvokeAsync` in place of `Invoke` and it *seems to work*, but it is important what `2` will be output **after** `1`.

Can I rely on assumption what if two `InvokeAsync` are called from same thread they will execute in the same order? My *winapi's nut* tells me it's true, but I want to be sure.

And another related question is same as linked one: if same method is called via `InvokeAsync` action from different threads, how good are chances to have it executed first for thread who calls `InvokeAsync` earlier?

P.S.: I have feeling question should be rephrased "How InvokeAsync works", but the word "order" is probably 100% candidate of what people (including me) will try to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check this out http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,1045

When you call InvokeAsync, an operation is put to PriorityQueue, so I suppose if you call several actions with the same priority, you can be confident that these actions will be executed with the same order.

Comment: This answer is very close to what I want to know. Ok, it uses `PriorityQueue`, so it **must** come in same order (at least my hopes have confirmation now). But I see a `lock` there, what does it do?

Comment: Looks like that in case of multiple threads it will be executed with the same order due to this lock.

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()` returns a `DispatcherOperation` object. It has a property `Task`:

> Gets a T:System.Threading.Task that represents the current operation.

You can use all operations a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supports. For example continue with the second dispatcher call.

```
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Log.Add("1")).Task.ContinueWith(() => {
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Log.Add("2"));
});
```

As Yuval Itzchakov stated, if you simply want to execute them in order, you can `await` the `InvokeAsync` call, because `DispatcherOperation` is `awaitable` (since it exposes a `GetAwaiter` method).

> Can I rely on assumption what if two InvokeAsync are called from same thread they will execute in the same order?

I would never rely on assumptions on the underlying system. It makes the system fragile (you never really know if that assumption is (still) true).

Comment: I don't want to await for `InvokeAsync` at all. Is that even possible: 1) do not await 2) ensure in order of `InvokeAsync`?

Comment: If you want to ensure explicitly that `2` is executed after `1` and dont want to use await, you have to use a continuation (`Task.ContinueWith`). I dont see any other option.

Answer (score 0):

[`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199422(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`DispatcherOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation(v=vs.110).aspx), which is an awaitable (it exposes a [`GetAwaiter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation.getawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx) method). If you want to guarantee execution order, you can `await` them, in the desired order:

```
async Task PerformanceCriticalMethodAsync()
{
    await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Log.Add("1"));
    ... some job
    await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Log.Add("2"));
}
```

Comment: `await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is basically simple `Invoke` (which is costly), I want to avoid loosing time to do "some job", only ensure in right order. I can await for first invoke before doing next, but the problem what I will have **many invokes** (given example is simplified), so `await` is bad for me as it will eat time needed to wait until task is finished. And I don't want to wait.

Comment: @Sinatr You don't synchronously block with `await`. Control is yielded back to the caller, as the thread itself is freed. You're free to execute more work in the meanwhile.

Comment: There is no caller. "Some job" part should run as soon as method is called and it's critical do not delay it with `Invoke`. I could use `queue` and producer/consumer, but my hope was what `InvokeAsync` already doing that. See @olegk answer.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't understand what you mean. *There is no caller* that makes no sense. If you want to start dealing with priorities, go right ahead. I think that will be more cumbersome to do.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain: I don't want to make method async, because caller **can be** blocked. What I means as "no caller" is what I don't care about him (ofc every method is called by something). I only care about "some job" what has to be executed as soon as method is called. It shouldn't be delayed **and** `Log.Add` should be executed in same order **without** delaying "some job".. if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a conclusion for myself:

> Whoever call `InvokeAsync` first will get its action serviced first.

It has nothing to do with normal `async` methods uncertainty "who will run first", because implementation of `InvokeAsync` is a pure thread-safe producer/consumer queue (can be seen in [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,1045), thanks to @olegk answer).