# Rising events without blocking and receiving events in the right order

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, asynchronous

This required some explanation first. There is a working thread which has to rise some event:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 123456789; i++)
    {
        ... // some job
        OnSomeEvent(i);
    }
});
```

Rising events synchronously will block the job until all event handlers have finished:

```
void OnSomeEvent(int i) => SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, new SomeEventArgs(i));
```

Asynchronous event rising will not block the job anymore (yay!)

```
void OnSomeEvent(int i) => Task.Run(() => SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, new SomeEventArgs(i)));
```

but now there is another problem: events are not received in the right order:

```
OnSomeEvent(1);
OnSomeEvent(2);
OnSomeEvent(3);
...

// event handler
SomeEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.I);

// possible output
1
3
2
```

**Question: how to implement asynchronous events rising which occurs in the right order?**

Recently I learned what `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` [uses queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32778051/1997232). It looks like I have to do something similar. And if I have to then: 1) should it be a job of a caller or 2) should I keep rising events synchronously and receiver has to organize producer/consumer to prevent job from blocking? Or maybe there is another way?

P.S.: this has nothing to do with `ContinueWhith`.. unless storing list of tasks is a proper solution. My concern is how to implement fire-and-forget events where: a) caller is not blocked 2) events are received in same order.

P.P.S.: I don't know how to make MCVE to reproduce the problem. It appears in real project with heavy UI, lots of threads, etc.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using events you want to use a queue which is FIFO, and simply de-queue once something is ready and process it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, which means trigger some event when something is added to queue. Caller will have to have queue and rise event. Subscribers (could be many) will receive event and do what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following `TaskQueue` in order to add asynchronous operations to a queue so that each one is started when the previous item in the queue finishes:

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    private Task previous = Task.FromResult(false);
    private object key = new object();

    public Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            var next = previous.ContinueWith(t => taskGenerator()).Unwrap();
            previous = next;
            return next;
        }
    }
    public Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            var next = previous.ContinueWith(t => taskGenerator()).Unwrap();
            previous = next;
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
private TaskQueue taskQueue = new TaskQueue();
private void OnSomeEvent(int i) => 
    taskQueue.Enqueue(() => Task.Run(() => SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, new SomeEventArgs(i))));
```

Comment: Looks promising, thanks. Chaining tasks into `ContinueWith` chain without blocking caller. And the greatest part is what `TaskQueue` is reusable for other ordered async events.

Comment: @Sinatr That's the idea, yes.  I've actually come across a number of situations in which such a queue has been useful, so it's not a particularly unique need.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) queue from the [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to maintain a queue of events.

You would create the queue as follows:

```
queue = new ActionBlock<SomeEventArgs>(item => SomeEvent?.Invoke(item));
```

Then you would add events to the queue like so:

```
queue.Post(new SomeEventArgs(value));
```

When the queue is no longer needed you do this:

```
queue.Complete();
```

After that, if you need to wait until any items still in the queue are processed, you can do this:

```
queue.Completion.Wait();
```

However, note that `queue.Completion` is in fact a `Task` so you would often use it with `await`.

Here's a complete example showing one approach (which doesn't keep a thread alive all the time just to process the event queue):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace Demo
{
    public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public SomeEventArgs(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public int Value { get; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        public delegate void SomeEventHandler(SomeEventArgs e);

        public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;

        ActionBlock<SomeEventArgs> queue;

        private void run()
        {
            queue = new ActionBlock<SomeEventArgs>(item => SomeEvent?.Invoke(item));

            // Subscribe to my own event (this just for demonstration purposes!)

            this.SomeEvent += Program_SomeEvent;

            // Raise 100 events.

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                OnSomeEvent(i);
                Console.WriteLine("Raised event " + i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Signalling that queue is complete.");
            queue.Complete();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for queue to be processed.");
            queue.Completion.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }

        private void Program_SomeEvent(SomeEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handled " + e.Value);
            Thread.Sleep(1); // Simulate load.
        }

        private void OnSomeEvent(int value)
        {
            queue.Post(new SomeEventArgs(value));
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires there to be an entire thread pool thread dedicated to just pumping this queue for the entirety of the objects lifetime (for each object, if there are several of them).  That's a really bad idea, especially when it's entirely unnecessary.  The thread pool is designed for short lived operations, not very long lived operations, and creating a new dedicated thread would be quite resource intensive, and not scale well if there are many instances of this object.

Comment: Actually, a better queue would be from the TPL. I'll have a think about that.

Comment: @Servy There we go - a version using the TPL which doesn't need a devoted thread.